# Filtering Questions (posts) by tag_name in TagController#index passing /tags?tag_name=something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, filter

I am trying to get my TagsController#index action to display only the Questions that contain certain tags when passing the search parameter tag_name. I am not getting an error just can't get the filter to work correctly such that upon receiving the `/tags?tag_name=something` url, only those questions are displayed . Here is the setup:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :question

   def self.search(str)
     return [] if str.blank?
     cond_text   = str.split.map{|w| "tag_name LIKE ? "}.join(" OR ")
     cond_values = str.split.map{|w| "%#{w}%"}
     all(:order => "created_at DESC", :conditions =>  (str ? [cond_text, *cond_values] : []))
   end

end
```

and

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

tag link that would send the URL to the TagsController looks like this:

```
<%= link_to(tag_name, tags_path(:tag_name => tag_name)) %>
```

and outputs:

```
/tags?tag_name=something
```

In my `/views/tags/index.html.erb` view I am calling the questions by rendering a partial `/views/questions/_question.html.erb`.

```
<%= render :partial => @questions %>
```

When I send the URL with the search parameter nothing happens. Here is my TagsController#index action:

```
def index
    @tags = Tag.search(params[:search]).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
    @tagsearch = Tag.search(params[:search])
    @tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, 
       :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 100)

    @questions = Question.all( :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 50)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tags }
    end
  end
```

How can I properly filter questions displayed in the `/views/tags/index.html.erb` file for the parameter `tag.tag_name`?

UPDATE:

It appears that I have figured this out. I just had to replace:

```
<%= link_to(tag_name, tags_path(:tag_name => tag_name)) %> x<%=tag_count%>
```

with

```
<%= link_to(tag_name, tags_path(:search => tag_name)) %> x<%=tag_count%>
```

Comment: This does't answer your question, but you should be using has_many :through instead of just a has many. This would minimize database size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have figured this out. I just had to replace:

```
<%= link_to(tag_name, tags_path(:tag_name => tag_name)) %> x<%=tag_count%>
```

with

```
<%= link_to(tag_name, tags_path(:search => tag_name)) %> x<%=tag_count%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is in the format of your SQL like clause, you need the format to be

```
%<query-here>%
```

Comment: so just change that line to %<LIKE>% or am I off? Not really sure what you mean because I am new to ruby and rails (and anything else that involved programming).

Comment: you change the ? in the SQL statement to "%#{query}%"